# Wrote stack traces to tombstoned

Tags: android, tcp

I try to use TCP protocol in Android to connect to another app. My connection is fine but the issue is when I try to receive message. At first, I receive message successfully but after a few days I try to run my app again and have this lines in logcat and my app crash.

`Thread[6,tid=17947,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x76d19dc400,peer=0x13840000,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3` 
`Wrote stack traces to tombstoned`

This is my TCP code

```
public class TCP {
    String ip;
    static Socket socket;
    private Context sContext;
    private static TCP TCP;


    private static PrintWriter pt;
    private static DataInputStream dataInputStream;

    public TCP(Context context) {
        sContext = context;
    }

    public static TCP getInstance(Context context) {
        if (TCP == null) {
            TCP = new TCP(context);
        }
        return TCP;
    }

    public void setIP(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public void createConnection() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void SendMessageTask(String mess, Object data){
        try {
            pt = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            var mess1 = new Message(mess,data);
            var str_mess = mess1.toString() + "\n\r\n";
            pt.write(str_mess);
            pt.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String Receive() {
        String mess = "";
        try {
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            mess = dataInputStream.readUTF() + "\n";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Socket", "Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mess;
    }

}
```

And This is my connection code

```
        String serverIp = mEditTextIpAddress.getText().toString();
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _TCP = new TCP(ConnectActivity.this);
                _TCP.setIP(serverIp);
                _TCP.createConnection();

                Intent i = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        };

        if (serverIp.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toast_blank_ip),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //TODO: change this one in step 2
            mConnectButton.startAnimation(() -> null);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

My MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        statistics = findViewById(R.id.statistic);
        statistics.setText(TCP.getInstance(MainActivity.this).Receive());
```

Comment: That means your app crashed in C level code, and the C stack trace was written to a tombstone file.  Where that is can vary a bit between devices.

Comment: But I can see a major problem-  your connection code isn't being run before you call Receive.  That means your socket isn't going to be properly initialized, which could result in that problem.  If you think you are running that code before receive-  you likely have a mess of your multithreading code.  Which seems likely anyway-  creating threads and sending intents from the background like that is a smell at a minimum.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you said, I am running the connection code before I call Receive function. I don't know like how to fix so that it's not a mess in my multithreading code. Do you have any idea with that ? @Gabe